# How to execute groovy script on Jenkins server locally

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

I already have my Jenkins installed and running, I tried to run a Groovy script on my local Jenkins server itself:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar  -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth admin:password groovy test.groovy
```

but I got:

`ERROR: This command is requesting the -remoting mode which is no longer supported. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/cli-command-requires-channel`

So if I want to execute a Groovy script on Jenkins server locally, not through the interface such as `JENKINS_URL/script`, what should I do?

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try to use:

```
jar jenkins-cli.jar  -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth admin:password groovy = < test.groovy
```

Credits to [cli ibook](https://imarslo.gitbook.io/ibook/jenkins/script/cli), see also http://localhost:8080/cli/command/groovy